# ansible using multiple strategies with strategy plugin

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using ansible 2.1 and would like to figure out how (if possible) to specify more than one strategy in the ansible.cfg file for running ansible playbooks.  Currently, I am using **debug** strategy but would like to use **free** or other strategies as needed.

```
strategy: debug
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_strategies.html) you can set strategy on per play basis:

```
- hosts: all
  strategy: free
  tasks:
  ...
```

Comment: spaciba @Konstantin - can we set more than one strategy (I'm trying to use both debug and free)

Comment: As far as I know, NO. Strategy – is how Ansible runs your tasks, so you can't combine them. Although, you may write your own stratagy plugin to accomplish what you want.